What does Colossus cosmology.sigma() return
Can anyone tell me if the Colossus cosmology.sigma() function returns variance, which is sigma^2, or sigma and I have to square it to get variance?  All of the documentation regarding this is completely ambiguous and I cannot find an answer.  I want to pass the return value to EPS calculation function and don't know if I need to square it first.  In the Colossus documentation, the function is called "sigma" but the verbiage says it is "variance".  Which is it?  Please help.

The documentation says "rms variance", which means $\sigma$ and not $\sigma^2$. ("rms" is short for "root mean square".) I can't attest that the code returns the correct thing, but the documentation at least is clear to me.
